# How to call an Activity inside another Activity in Microsoft Workflow?

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I have created a Native activity and I need to call another activity on a Bookmark Resume call. My First Activity name is "Apply" and Second activity is called "Approve". In Apply, i have created a property as below.

```
  public Approve Approve
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

and then I have registered the CacheMetadata as below.

```
        metadata.AddImplementationChild(this.Approve);
        base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
```

And then "OnResumeBookmark" method, Im scheduling it.

```
        this.Approve = new Approve();
        this.Approve.ID = context.GetValue(this.ID);
        OutArgument<string> res = this.Approve.Result;
        context.ScheduleActivity(this.Approve);
```

But When it runs, it gives me the below error.

**The provided activity was not part of this workflow definition when its metadata was being processed.  The problematic activity named 'Approve' was provided by the activity named 'Apply'.**

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to activity development:

- The Private Implementation Route
- The Public Implementation Route

It appears you are working on the **private implementation strategy** from your question, but I'll provide sample code for both ways below.

> The Private Implementation Way

In this approach, the `Apply` activity is responsible for setting up everything about the `Approve` child activity. We wire up the `ID` property using the WF `Variable<string>` object. Also, we inform the WF run time that the `Approve` activity can be scheduled by the `Apply` activity, just like you have in your code sample.

```
public class Approve : CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<string> Something
    {
        get; set;
    }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var message = string.Format("Approval of {0} in process... please wait.", this.Something.Get(context));
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

public class Apply : NativeActivity
{
    private readonly Approve approve;
    private readonly Variable<string> thingToApproveVar;

    public Apply()
    {
        this.thingToApproveVar = new Variable<string>();
        this.approve = new Approve();
        this.approve.Something = new InArgument<string>(this.thingToApproveVar);
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(this.thingToApproveVar);
        metadata.AddImplementationChild(this.approve);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Approving...");
        this.thingToApproveVar.Set(context, "Hello");
        context.ScheduleActivity(this.approve, this.OnApprovalCompleted);
    }

    private void OnApprovalCompleted(NativeActivityContext activityContext, ActivityInstance instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Apply succeeded!");
    }
}
```

> The Public Implementation Way

The second approach in developing your activity is to define your `Apply` activity to simply schedule the `Approve` activity. The `CacheMetadata` method needs a slight tweak for this though, by using the `AddChild` method instead of the `AddImplementationChild` method.

```
public class Apply : NativeActivity
{
    public Apply()
    {
    }

    public Approve Approve { get; set; }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddChild(this.Approve);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.ScheduleActivity(this.Approve, this.OnApprovalCompleted);
    }

    private void OnApprovalCompleted(NativeActivityContext activityContext, ActivityInstance instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Apply succeeded!");
    }
}
```

And to execute the "public implementation way", it would look like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new Sequence()
        {
            Activities =
            {
                new Apply()
                {
                    Approve = new Approve()
                    {
                        Something = "Hello World!"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try this and get back to you. As a workaround, When I did was creating a "workflowapplication" inside the APPLY and call APPROVE. It works. But, Inside APPROVE im calling a Rest Service. before the rest call finishes, it goes to the completed delegate which is in APPLY. :(

Comment: Are you creating a [WorkflowApplication] inside the [Apply] activity? That is not a good idea. I recommend making another question (or update this question) with that scenario with sample code, so we have a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think i was over complicating things. I could have both activities in a sequence with a bookmark in between rather than calling an activity from an activity. I have tried that and its working fine. Thanks for your help.