# Windows Workflow Custom Activity: Error when evaluating expression which references a variable

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

I have the following WF activity which I've created to test the concept of executing an (vb) expression with a set of 'variables' that are accessible within that expression.

```
public class ExpressionEncapsulationActivity : NativeActivity<bool>
  {
    private readonly Collection<Variable> _variables = new Collection<Variable>();
    private readonly Collection<Activity> _activities = new BindingList<Activity>();
    private Assign _expressionEvaluationChild { get; set; }
    private Variable<bool> _expressionResultVariable;

    public Collection<Variable> Variables { get { return _variables; } }
    public InArgument<bool> Expression { get; set; }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
      base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
      DisplayName = "Expression Encapsulation";

      metadata.SetVariablesCollection(Variables);
      metadata.SetChildrenCollection(_activities);

      _expressionResultVariable = new Variable<bool>("evalResult");
      _expressionEvaluationChild = new Assign()
      {
        DisplayName = "Expression Encapsulation Assign",
        To = new OutArgument<bool>(_expressionResultVariable),
        Value = new InArgument<bool>((ctx) => Expression.Get(ctx))
      };

      metadata.AddImplementationVariable(_expressionResultVariable);
      metadata.AddImplementationChild(_expressionEvaluationChild);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
      context.ScheduleActivity(_expressionEvaluationChild, OnExpressionEvaluationComplete);
    }

    protected void OnExpressionEvaluationComplete(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance completedActivity)
    {
      Result.Set(context, _expressionResultVariable.Get(context));
    }

  }
```

And I'm trying to test the activity as follows:
( class ForEachActivityItem is simple and has an Id property on it )

```
  var testVarItem = new ForEachActivityItem()
  {
    Id = 2
  };
  var workflow = new ExpressionEncapsulationActivity()
  {
    Variables =
    {
      new Variable<ForEachActivityItem>("var", (ctx) => testVarItem)
    },
    Expression = new InArgument<bool>(new VisualBasicValue<bool>("var.Id = 1"))
  };
  var result = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(workflow);
  Assert.IsFalse(result, "Test #1");
```

But this test throws the error:

> System.Activities.InvalidWorkflowException: The following errors were
>   encountered while processing the workflow tree:
>   'VisualBasicValue': Compiler error(s) encountered processing
>   expression "var.Id = 2". 'var' is not declared. It may be inaccessible
>   due to its protection level.

I can't see why the variable (var) is not available to the expression as it's declared on a 'parent' activity to the expression's execution context (being the Assign child activity created within the ExpressionEncapsulationActivity activity).

It might be worth noting that the test works if the expression passed in does not reference a variable (e.g. "1 = 1"). It's also interesting that I **can** get this sort of expression working if I use a `Sequence` activity, setting its variable and adding an `Assign` child Activity to it which evaluates the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue stemmed from a lack of understanding of the distinction between private and public 'metadata'.

> More on this here:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068737/how-to-call-an-activity-inside-another-activity-in-microsoft-workflow

The former (private) is registered with metadata methods of the form AddImplementationXXX and the latter with methods of the form AddXXX (e.g. AddChild).

The private and public 'zones' do not mix well (at all?). Private child activities (of the type in my above question) do not have access to public variables for example. And the variable (in property Variables) being set in my question's test are public.

There is also a lot to be aware of concerning what happens in base.CacheMetadata() which (and I speak under correction) uses reflection to find appropriate properties to register for you. If you want more control of how children and variables are registered it's often better not to call base.CacheMetadata().

Another 'spanner' I encountered was that public variables defined within an Activity are not accessible within that activity - they are only accessible by (public) child activities. This makes it tricky implement a result-returning public child activity (e.g. NativeActivity), which returns a result in its Result property. The natural approach is to want to extract that result by binding 'Result' (an OutArgument) to a variable and then use variable.Get(context) to extract that result.

You can't do this. You need to implement a 'Completed' event method which takes the a 'result' parameter and use that. For example:

```
private void OnFuncEvaluationComplete(NativeActivityContext context,
                    ActivityInstance completedinstance, bool result)
{
  Result.Set(context, result); // Set my result to that returned by the child activity
}
```

And fun was had by all!