# Create nested custom WPF Activity and execute nested activity

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, uipath

I am trying to create a scope to contain a set of activities using C# & WPF for use within UiPath.

I am able to create a custom activity using the below class

```
using System.Activities;

namespace Custom_Activities
{
    public sealed class Scoped_Activity : Scoped_Activity_Template
    {
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Custom Activity Executing");
        }
    }
}
```

and I am able to create a scope to contain this activity using the below class

```
using System.Activities;

namespace Custom_Activities
{
    public class Custom_Activity_Scope : CodeActivity
    {
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Scope Executing");
        }
    }
}
```

and the below designer file

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner 
    x:Class="Custom_Activities.Custom_Activity_Scope_Designer"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sapc="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.Converters;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
                    xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
                    xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Uid="ResourceDictionary_1">
            <sapc:ArgumentToExpressionConverter x:Key="ArgumentToExpressionConverter" />
            <sapc:ModelToObjectValueConverter x:Key="ModelToObjectValueConverter" />




            <DataTemplate x:Key="Collapsed">

            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="Expanded">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <sap:WorkflowItemPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

            <Style x:Key="ExpandOrCollapsedStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource Expanded}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowExpanded}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource Collapsed}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Style="{DynamicResource ExpandOrCollapsedStyle}" Content="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>
</sap:ActivityDesigner>
```

When I run `Scoped_Activity` I get the desired output (The log message saying 'Custom Activity Executing')

When I run `Custom_Activity_Scope` I get the desired output (The log message saying 'Scope Executing')

However when I place the `Scoped_Activity` within the `Custom_Activity_Scope` I only get the message 'Scope Executing' so the `Scoped_Activity` doesn't seem to be executing.

I'm not quite sure what my next steps should be to execute the `Scoped_Activity` within `Custom_Activity_Scope`

[image: Screenshot of nested activity]

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when I place the Scoped_Activity within the Custom_Activity_Scope?" Inherit? Like: public class Custom_Activity_Scope : Scoped_Activity

Comment: @user10728126, I've added a screenshot to the question, hope that makes sense/helps

Comment: Both Execute methods in Activities do only some tracing, there is no code which search for nested activity and then calls Execute from it. There has to be code in Custom_Activity_Scope which searches for nested activities and explicitly executes them, like Sequence Activity does.

Comment: @recineshto that makes sense. Can the scope still inherit/implement from CodeActivity, looking around some sites mention using NativeActivity instead? Don't suppose you have any links to examples etc

Comment: @Conor, here on SO I have found following sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068737/how-to-call-an-activity-inside-another-activity-in-microsoft-workflow 
As you may see in provided sample, plumbing will be most of yours code :)

Comment: Thanks, however, that example would assume that the child activity is always of the type 'Approve' I'm looking for an example that will take any type of activity and execute it from within the scope

Comment: @Conor, another sample from SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521696/windows-workflow-custom-sequence-activity
This time, attempt is made to mimic Sequence :) and there is execution control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here on SO (following one of comments) you can find nice solution:
[Windows Workflow Custom Sequence Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521696/windows-workflow-custom-sequence-activity)

I have not run-it yet, but did tried it in VS2017 and it behaves as expected.

Only issue was to figure-out right assembly references.
Beside *System.Activities* and *System.Activities.Presentation*, reference ***System.Activities.Core.Presentation*** is needed.